# Openssl command line fails to verify detached smime signature created moments earlier

Tags: openssl, signature, verify, pkcs#7, smime

I'm using the command line interface of openssl 1.0.1b on OSX 10.6.

First I create a DSA key.

```
openssl dsaparam -noout -out privatekey.pem -genkey 1024
```

Next i create a self-signed certificate from that key.

```
openssl req -new -outform PEM -out certificate.pem -key privatekey.pem -keyform PEM -sha1 -x509 -days 1000
```

Next i use that certificate and key in order to create a detached smime signature of a file.

```
openssl smime -sign -in file.zip -out file.zip.signature -outform DER -inkey privatekey.pem -signer certificate.pem
```

Finally I immediately try to verify that same file/signature*

```
openssl smime -verify -in file.zip.signature -inform DER -content file.zip -noverify certificate.pem > /dev/null
```

But somehow I get a digest failure.

```
PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_signatureVerify:digest failure:pk7_doit.c:1097:
PKCS7 routines:PKCS7_verify:signature failure:pk7_smime.c:410
```

Nothing is changing the file, manual md5 hashes match before and after, yet somehow the signature digest is failing. Does anyone have any clue as to what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

`* *Note that -noverify is used to tell openssl to not warn me about the certificate being self-signed*

Answer (score 3):

I've figured out the issue.

Because I didn't use the -binary flag openssl was transforming \n in the input file to \r\n